# Receiving name of user launching application

Tags: c#, .net

How to get User name which is launching my app?
Code:

```
Environment.UserName
```

returns current logged user, but I want name of the user which is launching app(for example through run as administrator).

Answer (score 4):

Even when you run a program as administrator, you're running it as the same user (if the user has administrator rights).

`Environment.UserName` does in fact return the name of the user who runs the applications. Look in the Task Manager and you'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want the actual user that the application is running as (i.e. administrator) and not the logged in user.

In this case, you want to get the Name from the current [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.aspx):

```
var sCurrentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```